# How to use unitofwork outside of Controllers

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, unit-of-work

So, I'm honestly not even sure how to ask this question, since I lack experience in this topic. If there is information missing, just let me know and I'll add all I have.

I'm basically trying to add an Exception handling system in my web application by using a filter.

So below you can see the filter I created. In here I'm trying to reach my unitofwork, but I keep getting an exception on the `container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();` line.

```
public class LogExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var dependencyResolver = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver 
            as AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver;
        var container = dependencyResolver.Container;
        var uow = container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
    }
}
```

The exception I'm getting:

> **DependencyResolutionException was unhandled by user code**
>   An exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException'
>   occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No scope with a Tag matching
>   'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance
>   was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as
>   per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component
>   (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request
>   dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or
>   ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container
>   itself.

Here is the IUnitOfWork interface:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IBoothRepository BoothRepository { get; }
    IEventRepository EventRepository { get; }
    ILocationRepository LocationRepository { get; }
    IPersonRepository PersonRepository { get; }
    IProfessionalRepository ProfessionalRepository { get; }
    IRegistrationRepository RegistrationRepository { get; }
    IStakeholderRepository StakeholderRepository { get; }
    IStudentRepository StudentRepository { get; }
    IVisitRepository VisitRepository { get; }

    void SaveChanges();

    DbContextTransaction BeginTransaction();
}
```

Comment: I would revisit your IUnitOfWork interface.... surely it should not know about all the repositories, rather you would have a service, which would know the repositories AND the unit of work, and use them to perform a unit of work. In your current design you have to CHANGE YOUR INTERFACE every time you add a new repository. This is certainly not correct

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework (or LINQ) the data context is ALREADY an implementation of the Unit of Work pattern, so you don't need to re-do this at a higher level as well

Answer (score 2):

The *additional information* is your friend here:

> No scope [...] is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.)

An ExceptionFilter is a SingleInstance component, since it's generic (Single Instance) to all requests within the application instead of it having a specific instance be bound to a specific request.

They actually have a pretty decent [HowTo](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#provide-filters-via-dependency-injection) for Web API on the Autofac website which comes down to implementing the IAutofacExceptionFilter and using Property Injection to get the stuff resolved in your FilterAttribute.
There's also an [MVC HowTo](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#enable-property-injection-for-action-filters), which comes down to calling RegisterFilterProvider to enable Property Injection for filters.

Comment: You're dealing with a [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

Comment: The Generic ExceptionFilter might have a dependency on a logging service which should  not be a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you running a test, from where the AutoFacPerRequestScope has not been initialized ?
You might have to use PerLifeTimeScope lifetime instead of PerRequest Lifetime.